# Store a variable as variable in database

Tags: php, sql

Hello im building a multilenguaje app in php, this is the first time i handle multilenguaje, im trying to do it like this.

For months for example

i have a table "months" with  `id |  month`  estructure

in the users table i have `id | username | month_id`

my guess (bad guess) its that i can save for example $january direct on the database so in the php when its called, it looked for the defined variable.

$january = "january"; and if im on spanish web then i change this to $january = "Enero";

but this is not working (obviusly because it prints as a result of a call $january, Its saved as $january in the database)

How is the best method for what im trying to do.. cause im lost in this point.. and i need this estructure in the database for a lot of reasons i wont mention, right now,

thanks!

My code

This `$row2['months']`

Print this `$january`

Even when in the php code i have set $january = "enero";

Comment: A common approach is to save it as string "january" and use a translation adapter like phparray, gettext `_("january")` or Tmx to output.

Comment: like this $lang['$row2['months']']

Comment: If you want to store variables on tables, [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) them before insertion and [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) while retrieving. I believe using a language file would be a better approach.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get php to evaluate that variable, what you need to do is eval:

```
$january='Enero';
$row='$january';

echo $row;                     //Prints $january
echo PHP_EOL;
echo eval("return ".$row.";"); //Prints Enero
```

Here that is in ideOne: http://ideone.com/f0LCT0

Comment: i wouldn't eval columns from the database (in this case), this is an unnecessary securtiy risk.

Comment: @DreaminMediaQueretaro This answered your question but it's terrible advise. You shouldn't implement languages in the way you're planning. Have a look at Ihsans answer instead. It will be much simpler to maintain.

Comment: @Bart, it is not a good practice to just eval code. But this is the answer to the question he asked.

Answer (score 4):

You might rethink your strategy.

Example:

For 10 languages if you keep 10 php files defining the month names or actually all language locale words in, it will be sufficient and you can include them without disturbing the database.

```
<?php

 // this is words_en.php, you can make another like words_de.php etc.
 $months = array('january','february','march','april'....etc );

?>
```

If you structure your locale file consistently for instance:

```
 $msgs = array(
    'MSG1'=>'first message',...
 }
```

keeping only the references(like'MSG1') in your code and also in your database will be sufficient. For the months, you can keep them apart from $msgs since their use is specific and numeric indexing adds more consistency to coding for their case.

Note that this is not the only method for language locales but this is an easy to maintain version.

Comment: yeah this is what im trying to do... but how do i save it in the database like "january" and then , how or where do i specify lenguaje, yo mean this $lang['$row2['months']']

Comment: since you have the month as number like 1->january(or enero) it is not a problem, you just store the index of month like 1,2,3 etc. Edited the answer. Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You should save the users locale e.g. `en_US` in your table and base further translations on that value with a fallback to the default language.